# How to implement the "blog functionality" in WP using Timber and Twig?

Tags: wordpress, timber

I'm using timber and twig with wordpress trying to get the good old blog functionality. Problem is that i do not receive any posts when using the index.php (which is correct, right?)

When running this in index.php and assign a posts page in admin i get no posts. When running same code in a custom template file i get the posts. What on earth am i doing wrong here?

Index.php (no posts returned, wordpress predefined "blog" template, assigned as the posts page in settings)

```
<?php

/* File: index.php */

$context = Timber::context();

$args = array (
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'numberposts' => -1
);

$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);
$template = array('pages/news/index.twig');

Timber::render($template, $context);
```

News.php (posts returned, file assigned as a template for a page in wp-admin)

```
<?php

/* Template Name: News */

$context = Timber::context();

$args = array (
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'numberposts' => -1
);

$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);
$template = array('pages/news/index.twig');

Timber::render($template, $context);
```

index.twig (template)

```
{% if posts %}
  {% for p in posts %}
    {{ p|dump }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What if you use home.php instead of index.php?